# how to use two different table in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

In my app i have used table view for displaying the list of videos available and some details about that. i have used `UIWebview` to play the video when the user selects it, now i want to display the comments of the video in that `webView` below the player, what is the best way to do it, i know `UITableView` is good, but i have already used `tableView` delegate and customized it, now how can i use different `UITableview` delegate in the same file. Is there any better way to display comments other than `tableView`.

Comment: - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if ([tableView isEqual: _tableview1])
    {
    // do one thing
    }
    else if ([tableView isEqual:_tableview2])
    {
    // do other thing
    }
}

Comment: When you are comparing the two objects then you have to use the isEqual method.i.e if([tableView isEqual:_tableview1])

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use two `tableviews` on the same `viewcontroller` and you can differentiate between two by assigning them `tags`…or you can also check them by comparing their `memory` addresses.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
 if(tableView.tag==1){
    return [dataArray count];
 }else{
    return [dataArray1 count];
 }
}
```

or

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
 if(tableView==tableView1){
    return [dataArray count];
 }else{
    return [dataArray1 count];
 }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Check `tableView` parameter in your delegate/data source methods. Example:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (tableView == _tableview1)
    {
    // do one thing
    }
    else if (tableView == _tableview2)
    {
    // do other thing
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Define your another `UITableView` in **.h** file also and create and  give delegate and datasource as same like **tableView1**.

And just put condition when you want to use **tableView2** in delegate and datasource method such like

```
if(self.tableView2  == tableView)
{
  // write code for tableView-2 
}
else
{
  // write code for tableView-1 
}
```